# Show WordPress posts as a notification

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I would like to be able to show new WordPress posts from a specific `post_type` or `category` as a notification,

Like how facebook notifications work, there will be an icon, and if there is a new post i would like the icon to light up with a counter, and if the user has "Seen" or clicked the lighted icon it can go back to its original state.

Comment: So what you have code for it ? this is not platform where you will get full code with logic. you need to try it first. and then if you stuck at some where.. then expert will help you.

Comment: Thank you, I realize that, but i have absolutely no idea where to even start, or how it would even be done.

Comment: k. so you can start with custom table. create table for mange notification of new post with use id wise. do you have command in php ?

Comment: Ok so what i have done so far, is create the Custom post type "Notices", i can save and view the notices now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would sugest the answer from this question on the WP stackexchange:
[Looking for a theme to show unread/updated posts since last visit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/31800)

> What you're looking for is a combination of
>
> - [KB New Posts](http://adambrown.info/b/widgets/2008/02/20/new-plugin-kb-new-posts/), which shows visitors posts that they have not yet read
> - [Smart Unread Comments](http://inner.geek.nz/archives/2005/02/11/wordpress-plugin-smart-unread-comments/)
> - and some notification bar system, one of [these four](http://kissingcrust.com/4-impressive-notifications-bars-and-worth-mentioning-for-your-wordpress-blog/) may make a good choice
>
> Of course you will have to couple them yourself to suit your needs and
>   requirements. As far as I know there is no such plugin for WordPress.
>
> Additional ones that you may want to dig in are:
>
> - [WP Since Last Visit](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-since-last-visit/) Plugin
> - [Published Articles Since Last Visit](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/published-articles-since-last-visit/)
>
> Again, none of them will work just like you're imagining it, probably,
>   so you'll have to write your own using the concepts those plugins use.